# How to restart Express server in Azure Event Hub?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-eventhub

I am running an Azure Event Hub in my Express server and want to restart it if the Event Hub fails.
How can I do this?

```
import { Application } from "./Application";
import { clientControllers } from "./lib/clients";
import { CreateDeliveryEventHub } from "./lib/create-delivery-event-hub/create-delivery-event-hub";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { Log } from "lib-nodejs-shared";

(async () => {
  try {
    //if running locally use the .env file
    config();

    // For each client configuration that includes "creating a delivery" through their own event hub
    const azureEventHub = new CreateDeliveryEventHub.Processor(clientControllers);
    const app = new Application(azureEventHub);
    app.start();
  } catch (e) {
    Log.error("Azure Event Hub Initialization Failure", { error: e, config });
  }
})();
```

Comment: You want to restart it automatically or manually?

Comment: automatically, if azure event hub has some failure or disconnection